# Change List View Header and Group Header Vertical Order

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using xamarin forms.
I have list view contains header and group header like below.

```
      <ListView x:Name="Groups" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        SeparatorVisibility="Default" RowHeight="100" HasUnevenRows="True" IsGroupingEnabled="True" Header="">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Height="50"  Text="{Binding GroupName}" TextColor="White" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.Header>

                <Grid BackgroundColor="#941a24" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" x:Name="Order" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" x:Name="Name"/>
               </Grid>

                </ListView.Header>


                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                               //items
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

What is happen is the header of the List View appears Vertically Above the Group Header but I want to show the group header above the header (without changing the list view Binding object) such that every time the group header appears the List view header appears below.

Comment: `The header of the List View appears before the Group Header`-didn't quite get that ? Can u provide a screenshot ?

Comment: @zackraiyan sorry for the misunderstood what I mean vertically above.

Comment: why not add required `Margin1 to it ?

Comment: sorry can you explain how with xamarin?

Comment: actually xamarin is not a factor here,it's all about xaml....Anyway,what i meant was,set required `Margin` for both the Group header and simple header.Just like you used `Margin="0,10,0,0"` in `ListView.Header>`'s `<Grid>`

Comment: No matters where you define the header / group reader in xaml, you will always get the list header above the group header and items. If you want *that every time the group header appears the List view header appears below*,  just change the group header template to be a viewcell and code the actual 'list header' inside it as you described

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza,learned something new today.. :)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza That's an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matters where you define the header/group header in your `XAML`, it'll be compiled and you'll always get the list header above the group header and items ([see more on official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance)).

If you want that *every time the group header appears the List view header appears below*, just change the group header template to be a `ViewCell` and code the actual 'list header' content inside it.

Something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Groups" 
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
          RowHeight="100" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          IsGroupingEnabled="True">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" 
                       TextColor="White"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Fill"
                       HeightRequest="50"/>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="#941a24" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="Order" 
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           TextColor="White"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Name"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           TextColor="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                   //items
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: for those who resort to access label text using x:Name inside the data template just use a separate content view then reuse it inside the data template.